# Mpdf generating blank pdf with stylesheet

Tags: php, css, mpdf

Mpdf is generating blank white page pdf when including stylesheet, and working fine when I remove the stylesheet `$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);` But I want to include the stylesheet.
Any help appreciated.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['pdf'])){
        ob_clean();
        flush();
      /*-------------------- for genearte pdf start -----------------*/
        include("mpdf/vendor/autoload.php");
        include('includes/db.php');
     
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
     
        //$html = '<h1>Welcome</h1>';
        $html = '<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover tablesorter pdf_border">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="pdf_border">
                        <th class="header pdf_border">Name</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody>'; ?>
        <?php
        
          $sqli        = "SELECT * FROM user";
          $resulti     = mysqli_query($connection,$sqli);
          while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulti))
          {                    
            $html .= '<tr class="pdf_border">
            <td class="pdf_border">'.$row['name'].'</td>   

            </tr>';
            } 
     
          $html .= '</tbody></table>'; 
          $path       = 'pdf/';
          $file_name ="webpreparations-".time().".pdf";
          $stylesheet =file_get_contents('css/bootstrap.min.css'); 
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);  //             
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2); 
          $mpdf->Output($path.$file_name, "D");
        }
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="pdf" class="pull-right btn btn-warning btn-large" style="margin-right:40px" value="Genarte PDF">
</form>
```

and getting corrupted pdf file if I remove `ob_clean(); flush();`

Comment: please make your mind whether your question is about mysql or css. they have nothing in common

Answer (score 0):

Add stylesheet using

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('path/your stylsheet.css'), \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
```